# Having an issue passing a variable from a while mysqli_fetch_array loop to another page so I can use it with $_GET on the other side

Tags: php, get

Hello I am trying to use $_GET to pass a variable over to the contact.php page mentioned, but the outcome is:

> /contact.php?firstname=

this is the link that im clicking to send the variable:

```
echo '<a href="contact.php?name="' . $email . '">';
```

This is the code to get the variable on the other side:

```
 <?php
      $name = $_GET['name'];
      echo $name ;
    ?>
```

Comment: What populates `$email`?

Comment: $email is populated by $email = $row['email']; which is in a while mysqli_fetch_array which is getting that data

Comment: Are you sure? It must not be.

Comment: I have tested it by echoing $email and it echoes the email address

Comment: while I am here though is there a way to pass two variables over using $_GET or is it only possible with one?

Comment: @CiaranBeatty you can pass as many as you like: `param1=1&param2=2&[...]`. Please read up on `$_GET`.

Comment: You can use an `&` and send multiple `GET` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing the `href` attributes value before you should be.

```
echo '<a href="contact.php?name="' . $email . '">';
                                ^
```

You need to remove that double quote so the value comes out in the attribute. As written currently your HTML will be:

```
<a href="contact.php?name=" email@example.com">
```

so use:

```
echo '<a href="contact.php?name=' . $email . '">';
```

Comment: Question should be closed as a typo if you're going to reopen.

Comment: That's why I left too @chris85 - just popped in today to see what was what. Hell, I don't even run my comment macro any more. Fighting a losing battle. I am soured on the experience.

Comment: Well thank you very much for your help @chris85 it helped me out loads!